# How to download GPM rainfall data automatically?

Tags: r, precipitation

How to download GPM rainfall data automatically?

I tried to use DownloadGPM.R Function, but I think I had problem with Axel download accelerator. I guess I need to declare Axel as environment variable (using Windows 7), is that right? Does somebody used this or something similar?

Comment: will download.file not suffice? (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html) can you add an example of your code that isn't working?

Comment: Just a thought, but you might have a quicker response at http://stats.stackexchange.com though I know R users lurk around here.  They have 13k question as opposed to our 1.3k about R.